# to open workbook from an array

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

this is my code where users can select multiple files and then they are compared with headers in master file and then data is copy pasted. the problem is that i do not know how to reference the workbooks from the array to run the code, one workbook at a time. previously for a single workbook i used the activate statement but i do not know how to do it for multiple workbooks in the array. the book names are stored in arrNames. Temp calc is the sheet where all the data has to be stored. any suggestions ?

thanks,

Mathew

Sub Test()

```
     Dim lastCol, lastRow As Long, k As Long, a As Variant, b As Variant, cmpRng As Range
    Dim mastCol As Long, mastRng As Range, n As Long
    Dim Wbk As Workbook
    Dim fileone
     Dim SelectedFiles As Object
     Dim arrNames As Variant
     Dim indx As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets("Temp Calc").Select
'Clear existing sheet data except headers
    Rows(1).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rows.Count - 1).ClearContents


    arrNames = Application.GetOpenFilename(Filefilter:="Workbooks (*.xlsx),*.xlsx", MultiSelect:=True)
       For i = 1 To UBound(arrNames, 1)


    Worksheets("Temp Calc").Select

       lastCol = Worksheets("Temp Calc").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
       lastRow = Worksheets("Temp Calc").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlDown).Row

    Set cmpRng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, lastCol))
    a = cmpRng
    mastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Set mastRng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, mastCol))
    b = mastRng

    For k = 1 To lastCol
        For n = 1 To mastCol
            If UCase(a(1, k)) = UCase(b(1, n)) Then
```

***Here i need the code to open workbook in array***

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2, n), Cells(lastRow, n)).Copy
                Windows("Dashboard_for_Roshan.xlsm").Activate
                Worksheets("Temp Calc").Select
                Cells(2, k).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
                False, Transpose:=False

                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next


        Next

    'Else

    'End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Exit Sub
        'Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try

```
sPath="C:\"
workbooks(sPath & arrNames(i)).open
```

where **i** is your loop counter through the array returned by `GetOpenFileName` and **arrNames** is your array

Comment: well, do you get an error, what is the error? Did you try debugging `?arrNames(i)` *in the Immediate Window at Runtime* to see if it is a workbook name including the path and filename **including extension**?

Comment: hello philip i did not see your latest edit, i was here to post the answer.but a similar modified version worked for me thanks a lot :)